# UITableViewCell dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier with custom initializer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using `[UITableView registerClass: forReuseIdentifier:]` and `[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]` in order to queue and dequeue UITableViewCells.

For example, in viewDidLoad:

`[self.storeTableView registerClass:[StoreLineGraphCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"StoreLineGraphCellIdentifier"];`

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

`StoreLineGraphCell *cell = (StoreLineGraphCell*)[self.storeTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StoreLineGraphCellIdentifier"];`

In doing this, the `initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` initializer is called for the UITableViewCell. The problem is that I need to use a custom initializer in order to create the cell with necessary options. For example, the ability to do something like this:

`StoreLineGraphCell *cell = [[StoreLineGraphCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:@"StoreLineGraphCell" isLocked:YES isUpcoming:YES];`

This doesn't seem possible with the `registerClass` & `dequeue` pattern. I'd like to keep it in an initializer as it should only be run once, not every time the cell is dequeued. Is there a proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: If the additional parameters depend on the row then you must set them separately (because of cell re-usage). If they are independent on the row then you can set them in your initWithStyle method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you follow the usual pattern for cell re-usage (as you do with register class & dequeue), I do not see an *easy to implement* way of doing that.

If I were you I would create an additional initialization method (not following the usual `init` pattern of obj-c) or simply setters and call that following the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` call.

```
StoreLineGraphCell *cell = (StoreLineGraphCell*)[self.storeTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StoreLineGraphCellIdentifier"];
[cell furtherInitWithLocked:YES andUpcoming:NO]; // ... or so
```

Comment: This is the current method I'm using. The problem here is that anything but the initializer will be called every time the cell is dequeued. My goal is to be able to run view-based code in the initializer, for performance reasons.

Comment: If that is of much importance to you, then don't register the cell subclass - which may not be compatible to using certain story board or nib file mechanisms. In that case dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier would return nil when the reuse queue is nil because it cannot allocate a new one. Then you check for nil and use your own alloc/init pattern.

Comment: That makes sense. I think that the headaches saved by being able to register & dequeue the cell is more important than the slight performance boost that I'm looking for; I'll probably stick to the method provided in your answer.

Comment: @HermannKlecker do you then have to set the cell's reuse identifier manually in your custom init?

Comment: @greenhouse, that depends. You can do that in a custom init or you can call the setter. If you use a XIB/NIB file or a storyboard then you would set it in the interface builder (from which any initialization in a custom init would be overwritten).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the correct registerClass and dequeue methods but for invoking/setting your custom properties you should configure creating a separate method and invoke it.

Instead of this:

```
StoreLineGraphCell *cell = [[StoreLineGraphCell alloc] 
initWithReuseIdentifier:@"StoreLineGraphCell" isLocked:YES isUpcoming:YES];
```

You can do this:

```
StoreLineGraphCell *cell = // get the dequeue cell 
[cell configure];
```

Inside the configure method you can set the properties as shown below:

```
-(void) configure 
{
   self.isLocked = YES; 
   self.isUpcoming = YES; 
}
```

Comment: See my comment on Hermann's response - the 'configure' method would be called every time the cell is dequeued.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common problem which I encounter today.
However, it can be solved like this.
Because the cell class registered before `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method called, after executed
 `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]`,
the cell always be not **nil** and return by
`- initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier`.
It seems like that you can not customize your own **init** method.
But, if you do not register cell class before, then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will return **nil** if the tableview has no reusable cells.
So, we should check cell value returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, if it is nil, then we can **init** it with our custom method.

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]
if (!cell) {
    cell = /* custom init method */
}
```

That's done!
If we want to customize subclass cell init method, so **do not register cell class before**.

Comment: do you then have to set the cells reuse identifier manually in your custom init?