# Dequeue UITableViewCell with a generic parameter

Tags: ios, uitableview, generics

Let's say we have a generic `UITableViewCell`:

```
class ControlTableViewCell<ControlType: UIControl>: UITableViewCell
```

Because when we need to create the cell we need to know the control type, we should disable this initializer:

```
@available(*, unavailable)
    override convenience init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        fatalError("Use init().")
    }
```

and only use the following initializer:

```
init(with control: ControlType, reuseIdentifier: String? = nil) {
        self.control = control
        super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        configureForControl()
    }
```

If I create a class that I want to use:

```
class DogTableViewCell: ControlTableViewCell<UIButton>
```

how would I go about dequeuing the reusable cells?
I would register first:

```
tableView.register(DogTableViewCell.cellClass,
                   forCellReuseIdentifier: DogTableViewCell.cellReuseIdentifier)
```

And then in the `cellForRowAt`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DogTableViewCell.cellReuseIdentifier,
                                         for: indexPath) as? DogTableViewCell ?? DogTableViewCell()
```

But because `dequeueReusableCell` uses `init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` we would crash at `fatalError("Use init().")`

Is there a good way to deal with this situation? I found a number of posts that ask the same question, but they all seem to want to set some properties that can be set later on, so no point in trying to use a custom initializer when dequeueing.. but in my case the class being generic, it needs to be initialized with a type.

Thanks for your help.

Similar posts: [UITableViewCell dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier with custom initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612737/uitableviewcell-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-with-custom-initializer)

Comment: The short answer is you can't use generics in this case. UIKit is Objective-C and doesn't know of Swift Generics.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all your initializers and add call configure method after the cell is created. For example,

```
func setControl(control: ControlType) {
    self.control = control
    configureForControl()
}
```

Call this methods after `dequeueReusableCell`